# Postfix: combine check_client_access and check_sender_access for Relayaccess

Tags: postfix, smtp-auth, whitelist

We have a mailserver running on Postfix.
Only authenticated users are allowed to send emails.

One client has a multifunction printer, which is configured to send scanned documents to an email recipient.
Unfortunately that printer is an older model and doesn't support smtp-auth.

I know I can use check_client_access to allow the static IP of this client for unauthenticated mail.
The following configuration would do that:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/allow_relay,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
  reject_unauth_pipelining
```

What I would like to do is to only accept unauthenticated email if the IP **and** the sender match with a list.

Just adding a check_sender_access to the sender restrictions would result in allowing Mail from the specified IP **or** the specified sender.

So how could I configure Postfix to combine those two, if possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By configuring a [**restriction class**](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) that checks the client IFF the sender matches $foo, or vice versa.